# Is it possible to call two servlet in single JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

The first servlet is to store data in database while the other is for sending email.
If it is possible, how?

Comment: A JSP *is* a servlet. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide more information on what exactly you want to accomplish?
For example:

Are these two servlets called by two separate actions in the JSP    (e.g. two different links) or do you want both servlets to be called    from one action? If so, you could forward from one servlet to the    other after its work is done.

When you are done the necessary work in the first servlet (e.g. store    data in the database) you can then add code similar to the following    snippet to the doGet method of the first servlet:

```
javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/yourSecondServlet");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

This will forward the request on to "/yourSecondServlet" where you    can do your other work (e.g. send an email)

Or are you asking  how to include two servlets in one JSPs?
If so, you can use the jsp:include action: 
`<jsp:include page="yourServlet" />`

Comment: How I'll gonna forward it to the other servlet?

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide an example of forwarding from one servlet to another.